# How to select all tables with column name and update that column

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I want to find all the tables in my db that contain the column name Foo, and update its value to 0, I was thinking something like this, but I don't know how to place the UPDATE on that code, I plan on having this statement on the Events inside the MySQL database, I'm using WAMP, the idea is basically having an event run daily which sets all my 'Foo' Columns to 0 without me having to do it manually

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name LIKE 'Foo'
```

Comment: This won't fix your problem or be useful, but when we use SQL we know the columns we want to work with, we don't search for them. If we need to find the column or the table, that means we're doing something wrong and we should be sent to jail because of it. If this were a cartoon, Wile E. Coyote would be going back to the drawing board.

Comment: i get your point, while e coyote did that 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not in a single statement.

To get the names of all that tables that contain column named `Foo`:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name
  FROM information_schema.columns 
  WHERE column_name = 'Foo'
```

Then, you'd need an UPDATE statement for each table. (It's possible to do update multiple tables in a single statement, but that would need to be an (unnecessary) cross join.) It's better to do each table separately.

You could use dynamic SQL to execute the UPDATE statements in a MySQL stored program (e.g. PROCEDURE)

```
  DECLARE sql VARCHAR(2000);
  SET sql = 'UPDATE db.tbl SET Foo = 0';
  PREPARE stmt FROM sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

---

If you declare a cursor for the select from information_schema.tables, you can use a cursor loop to process a dynamic `UPDATE` statement for each table_name returned.

```
  DECLARE done TINYINT(1) DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE sql  VARCHAR(2000);

  DECLARE csr FOR
  SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE `',c.table_schema,'`.`',c.table_name,'` SET `Foo` = 0') AS sql
    FROM information_schema.columns c
   WHERE c.column_name = 'Foo'
     AND c.table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema');
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN csr;
  do_foo: LOOP
     FETCH csr INTO sql;
     IF done THEN
        LEAVE do_foo;
     END IF;
     PREPARE stmt FROM sql;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP do_foo;
  CLOSE csr;
```

(This is just an rough outline of an example, not syntax checked or tested.)

**FOLLOWUP**

Some brief notes about some ideas that were probably glossed over in the answer above.

To get the names of the tables containing column `Foo`, we can run a query from the `information_schema.columns` table. (That's one of the tables provided in the MySQL `information_schema` database.)

Because we may have tables in multiple databases, the table_name is not sufficient to identify a table; we need to know what database the table is in. Rather than mucking with a "`use db`" statement before we run an `UPDATE`, we can just reference the table `UPDATE db.mytable SET Foo...`.

We can use our query of `information_schema.columns` to go ahead and string together (concatenate) the parts we need to create for an UPDATE statement, and have the SELECT return the actual statements we'd need to run  to update column `Foo`, basically this:

```
UPDATE `mydatabase`.`mytable` SET `Foo` = 0
```

But we want to substitute in the values from `table_schema` and `table_name` in place of `mydatabase` and `mytable`. If we run this SELECT

```
SELECT 'UPDATE `mydatabase`.`mytable` SET `Foo` = 0' AS sql
```

That returns us a single row, containing a single column (the column happens to be named `sql`, but name of the column isn't important to us). The value of the column will just be a string. But the string we get back happens to be (we hope) a SQL statement that we could run.

We'd get the same thing if we broke that string up into pieces, and used CONCAT to string them back together for us, e.g.

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE `','mydatabase','`.`','mytable','` SET `Foo` = 0') AS sql
```

We can use that query as a model for the statement we want to run against `information_schema.columns`.  We'll replace `'mydatabase'` and `'mytable'` with references to columns from the `information_schema.columns` table that give us the database and table_name.

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE `',c.table_schema,'`.`',c.table_name,'` SET `Foo` = 0') AS sql
  FROM information_schema.columns 
 WHERE c.column_name = 'Foo'
```

There are some databases we definitely do *not* want to update... `mysql`, `information_schema`, `performance_schema`. We either need whitelist the databases containing the table we want to update

```
  AND c.table_schema IN ('mydatabase','anotherdatabase')
```

-*or*- we need to blacklist the databases we definitely do not want to update

```
  AND c.table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema')
```

We can run that query (we could add an `ORDER BY` if we want the rows returned in a particular order) and what we get back is list containing the statements we want to run.  If we saved that set of strings as a plain text file (excluding header row and extra formatting), adding a semicolon at the end of each line, we'd have a file we could execute from the `mysql>` command line client.

(If any of the above is confusing, let me know.)

---

The next part is a little more complicated. The rest of this deals with an alternative to saving the output from the SELECT as a plain text file, and executin the statements from the `mysql` command line client.

MySQL provides a facility/feature that allows us to execute basically *any* string as a SQL statement, in the context of a MySQL stored program (for example, a stored procedure. The feature we're going to use is called *dynamic SQL*.

To use *dynamic SQL*, we use the statements `PREPARE`, `EXECUTE` and `DEALLOCATE PREPARE`.  (The deallocate isn't strictly necessary, MySQL will cleanup for us if we don't use it, but I think it's good practice to do it anyway.)

Again, *dynamic SQL* is available *ONLY* in the context of a MySQL stored program. To do this, we need to have a string containing the SQL statement we want to execute. As a simple example, let's say we had this:

```
DECLARE str VARCHAR(2000);
SET str = 'UPDATE mytable SET mycol = 0 WHERE mycol < 0';
```

To get the contents of `str` evaluated and executed as a SQL statement, the basic outline is:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM str;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The next complicated part is putting that together with the query we are running to get string value we want to execute as SQL statements. To do that, we put together a cursor loop. The basic outline for that is to take our SELECT statement:

```
SELECT bah FROM humbug
```

And turn that into a cursor definition:

```
DECLARE mycursor FOR SELECT bah FROM humbug ;
```

What we want to is execute that and loop through the rows it returns. To execute the statement and prepare a resultset, we "open" the cursor

```
OPEN mycursor;
```

When we're finished with it, we're goin to issue a "close", to release the resultset, so the MySQL server knows we don't need it anymore, and can cleanup, and free up the resources allocated to that.

```
CLOSE mycursor;
```

But, before we close the cursor, we want to "loop" through the resultset, fetching each row, and do something with the row.  The statement we use to get the next row from the resultset into a procedure variable is:

```
FETCH mycursor INTO some_variable;
```

Before we can fetch rows into variables, we need to define the variables, e.g.

```
DECLARE some_variable VARCHAR(2000);
```

Since our cursor (SELECT statement) is returning only a single column, we only need one variable. If we had more columns, we'd need a variable for each column.

Eventually, we'll have fetched the last row from the result set. When we attempt to fetch the next one, MySQL is going to throw an error.

Other programming languages would let us just do a `while` loop, and let us fetch the rows and exit the loop when we've processed them all. MySQL is more arcane. To do a loop:

```
mylabel: LOOP
  -- do something
END LOOP mylabel;
```

That by itself makes for a very fine infinite loop, because that loop doesn't have an "exit". Fortunately, MySQL gives us the `LEAVE` statement as a way to exit a loop. We typically don't want to exit the loop the first time we enter it, so there's usually some conditional test we use to determine if we're done, and should exit the loop, or we're not done, and should go around the the loop again.

```
 mylabel: LOOP
     -- do something useful
     IF some_condition THEN 
         LEAVE mylabel;
     END IF;
 END LOOP mylabel;
```

In our case, we want to loop through all of the rows in the resultset, so we're going to put a `FETCH` a the first statement inside the loop (the something useful we want to do).

To get a linkage between the error that MySQL throws when we attempt to fetch past the last row in the result set, and the conditional test we have to determine if we should leave...

MySQL provides a way for us to define a `CONTINUE HANDLER` (some statement we want performed) when the error is thrown...

```
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
```

The action we want to perform is to set a variable to TRUE.

```
 SET done = TRUE;
```

Before we can run the SET, we need to define the variable:

```
 DECLARE done TINYINT(1) DEFAULT FALSE;
```

With that we, can change our LOOP to test whether the `done` variable is set to TRUE, as the exit condition, so our loop looks something like this:

```
 mylabel: LOOP
     FETCH mycursor INTO some_variable;
     IF done THEN 
         LEAVE mylabel;
     END IF;
     -- do something with the row
 END LOOP mylabel;
```

The "do something with the row" is where we want to take the contents of `some_variable` and do something useful with it. Our cursor is returning us a string that we want to execute as a SQL statement. And MySQL gives us the *dynamic SQL* feature we can use to do that.

NOTE: MySQL has rules about the order of the statements in the procedure. For example the `DECLARE` statement have to come at the beginning. And I think the CONTINUE HANDLER has to be the last thing declared.

---

Again: The *cursor* and *dynamic SQL* features are available *ONLY* in the context of a MySQL stored program, such as a stored procedure. The example I gave above was only the example of the *body* of a procedure.

To get this created as a stored procedure, it would need to be incorporated as part of something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myproc $$

CREATE PROCEDURE myproc 
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

   -- procedure body goes here

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Hopefully, that explains the example I gave in a little more detail.

Comment: that is a super awesome answer, but im afraid its way far advanced for my current knowledge, im trying to get it to work , but failing miserably

Comment: @nonaxanon: There's two steps:  identifying the tables that have a column  named `Foo`. A query from `information_schema.columns` can get us those table names. Those tables can be in multiple databases, so we also need to get `table_schema` along with `table_name`, so we can write `UPDATE db.table_name SET ..`.  If we leave `db.` off, that would be a reference to that table in the current database, and we can avoid mucking with "`use db`" statements to change the current database. In our query of to get the table_name, we can use CONCAT to string together the whole UPDATE statement...

Comment: @nonaxanon: I've added a **FOLLOWUP** to my answer to explain the example procedure body I showed. Something like I showed will work as part of a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This should get all tables in your database and append each table with update column foo statement Copy and run it, the copy the output and run as sql

`select concat('update ',table_name,' set foo=0;') from information_schema.tables`
`where table_schema = 'Your database name here' and table_type = 'base table';`